# Union yielding empty shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, union

I'm just starting using QGIS. I have run a couple of geoprocessing tasks and the results look good but I'm trying Union and am not having much success.

The main one I'm trying to do is, I have a city corporate boundary and two types of road data - road centerlines and ROW boundaries. I am trying to union the corporate boundary with each one separately, and in both cases, when I run it the resulting shapefile seems to be empty.

The original vector files (roads and corporate boundaries) are all from geodatabases and the output is shapefile.

Any assistance would be help, maybe it's already been covered elsewhere here and I just didn't see it.

[image]

[image]

---

Ok, that seemed to work. See below.

[image]

Now, my next step is I'm trying to polygonize. But I'm getting an error message. Basically what I'm trying to do is divide the city into blocks so I can assign a value to each block. Maybe I should post this as a separate topic but I'll try here. I'm not sure if I'm getting the error because of something about the lines or someting in the attribute table... Or something else. Here's a closeup of what the street centerlines look like.

[image]

Maybe I need to clean up the lines or something, not sure. But anyway here's the error message I get when I run it.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "ROW boundaries"?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Can you please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of sample area showing your centerlines and ROW boundaries?  What are "ROW boundaries" - does ROW stand for Right of Way?

Comment: I'll try to get some screenshots here soon. Yes, right of way boundaries.

Comment: For those asking, ROW means Right of Way, the entire area of the road lanes, shoulder, sidewalks and ditch.

Comment: "Maybe I should post this as a separate topic but I'll try here." You should only post this as a new question because this is a focused Q&A site. Please cut/paste the new question into a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your roads and corporate boundaries are polylines. As such, a union would only work for line segments which are identical. 
[image]

You need to convert your boundary data to polygons, using the `Lines to Polygons` tool (or similar), and then perform the union with the resulting corporate boundary polygon.

[image]